# How do I plot the yearly mean of a large dataset conditional to the information of another column?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with millions of enterprises, their classifications as STARTUPS or NOTS, and their yearly revenue.

The data looks like this:

[image]

And I want to calculate and plot the yearly means of the group of companies that are STARTUPS and the groups of companies that are NOT STARTUPS. In other words, I want to calculate and plot the means of the revenue of the STARTUPS in 1998, 1999, 2000,.... and the means of the NOT STARTUPS in 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001.....

How can I do that?

Ps. When I try to calculate the mean of each column separately, for some reason the results are coming as NaN and I don't know why. For example, when I run the code mean(data$1998, na.rm = TRUE) the result is NaN.

Comment: Note that  `mean(data$`1998`, na.rm = TRUE)` is the right syntax then  `mean(data$1998, na.rm = TRUE)`. I will encourage data exploration to understand what are data. Simply do `summary(yourdata)` to see if there's any missing values

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: it is difficult to say the reason for NaNs without actually looking at your data. The answer below is the answer to your original question.

It is always good to give a sample data so that we recreate. For you example I have create a dummy data and showed how it can be done.

```
IDs <- 
data.frame(enterprise = letters,
       classification = sample(c('STARTUP','NOT STARTUP'), length(letters), replace = TRUE))

dat <-
as.data.frame(matrix(sample(200:600, length(letters) * 7), nrow = length(letters), ncol = 7))
names(dat) <- 1998:2004

final.dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(IDs, dat))
```

`final.dat` looks similar to your data.

First thing I would do is to convert the data into a long format

```
  library(tidyr)

  final.dat_long <- tidyr::gather(final.dat, yearRef, revenue, `1998`:`2004`)
```

Now group by classification and yearRef to get mean of each classification and year combination

```
summary <- final.dat_long %>% group_by(classification, 
 yearRef) %>% 
 summarise(meanRevenue = mean(revenue))
```

For plotting, there are many tools. I am using ggplot

```
 library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(summary, aes(x = yearRef, y = meanRevenue, fill 
  = classification)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')
```

[image]